# Admob ads is not displaying

Tags: java, android, admob

Pls help me... I just finished my first android app and wanted to include admob ads but the ads are not showing

How can i solve this problem? I also used the test ads but that one doesnt display also

My MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private AdView mAdView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    
    Fragment fr = new CoursesFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fr);
    ft.commit();

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
```

.....

```
}
```

My Courses Fragment. I used banner ads here

```
 private AdView mAdView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_courses, container, false);
    ....

    mAdView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

My Question Activity. I used interstitial ads here

```
 private Context context;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_question);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-pub-2005641929118957/8785xxxx");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
    action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    context = this;
    ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_level3qq);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
         ....
}
```

}

My fragment layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".CoursesFragment">



 ......
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-200564192911895/1290xxxxx">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My Android Manifest file includes the below

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-2005641929118957~2331645520" /> <
```

i have also imported and added the google play services into my sdk

The error message i get from my logcat concerning the ads

```
 E/Flurry: Ad server responded with the following error(s):
02-25 18:27:19.944 2756-24973/? E/Flurry: Adunit is not active



? E/AsyncOperation: operation=xlb, opStatusCode=12009 [CONTEXT service_id=45 ]
OperationException[Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12009, resolution=null}]
    at atnm.g(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):1)
    at atnm.fW(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):29)
    at abcx.run(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):9)
    at bqlt.run(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):2)
    at tmw.c(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):6)
    at tmw.run(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):7)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at tsu.run(:com.google.android.gms@210214017@21.02.14 (040306-352619232):0)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

invalid stream - problem with parameter iterator in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000008/AdsDynamite.apk for method void com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.event.p.a(java.lang.Object)
```

Comment: are the ads just not showing or you have any errors produced ? please clarify this point and if there are any errors post them with your question

Comment: The ads do not show at all. It is as if i added nothing... even with my connection to the internet

Comment: are you using your ad id from admob ? or test unit id?

Comment: i am using my ad id sir

Answer (score 0):

to Test your ads you can't use your live ad id  you should instead use testing id

```
    interstitial test id : ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
    banner test id: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
```

replace your ids with these test ids to be able to see your ads in testing mode

from your code everything looks good the implementation seems correct but you are not able to see the ad since its a live ad not a test ad .

Comment: I will try to test the ads... i will notify if it works sir

Comment: Hello sir, the test ads are also not displaying... I still dont know what the problem is

Comment: if the ads are not showing yet at all then its sure the RUN has errors please check the log when running the app for error or warnings such as "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet" or try pasting it in the question

Comment: I checked the logcat... the error it gives me pertaining to ads is that the adunit is not active

Comment: I get blank ads when using test ads. What do you see?

Comment: Nothing... My app just remains the same way... No changes

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this
[quick-start](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Make sure you include this in the manifest file

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
```

> Test AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713

[The source for the Test Admob app ID](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Also you can find here the [Testing ids](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

> App Open: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/3419835294
>
> Banner:   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111
>
> Interstitial:     ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712
>
> Interstitial Video:   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433
>
> Rewarded:     ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917
>
> Rewarded Interstitial:    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5354046379
>
> Native Advanced:  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110
>
> Native Advanced Video:    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115

replace your ids with these test ids to be able to see your ads in testing mode